# why my character is not scanned using scanf ( C language)

Tags: c, scanf

In the following code , my character is not being stored inside the character ... can anybody tell me what's wrong ? :

```
char z;
printf("A  or B ?\n ");
scanf("%c",&z);
printf("%c",z);
```

Comment: Did you include the `#include<stdio.h>`?

Comment: what is the output of `printf("%c",z);`? could you put another `scanf(..);` after `printf(..)`?

Comment: It works for me (when I wrap it in a main program and add `#include <stdio.h>`). I run the program and type `A`, then press Enter; it prints `A`.  You may be losing the output due to the lack of a newline; try changing `printf("%c",z);` to `printf("%c\n", z);`

Comment: @user1592784: Is there code before this that takes in input? If so there's probably left over junk in `stdin` that you haven't read yet (like a `'\n'`) that's being stored in `z` before you have a chance to enter any input (which you say in a comment to an answer below). What does `printf("%x", z);` output?

Comment: printf("A or B ?\n ");
scanf("%c,%c",&dummy,&z);

printf("%c \n",z); --> "╠"
printf("%x \n", z); --> "ffffffcc"

Comment: i replaced the scanf with 2 getchar's for dummy and Z and it worked ... can anyone help me with explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

read another dumy character before the wanted char:

```
char dumy;
scanf("%c%c",&dumy,&z);
```

Comment: You could actually use `%*c` to not actually scan that character, thus no other variable is needed.

Comment: I did this : 
printf("A or B ?\n ");
scanf("%c,%c",&dummy,&z);

printf("%c \n",z);

but the printed symbol is not what i typed : "╠"

Comment: @user1592784: in the scanf statement there is no `,` between `%c` ;)